Randomized Pascal's triangle: What is the average of all the numbers?
This question was posted on MSE. It received some interesting responses, but no definite answer.

Let's build a variation of Pascal's triangle. We write $1$'s going down the sides, as usual. Then for each number inside the triangle, we flip a biased coin, with probability of Heads $p$.

Heads: write the sum of the two numbers above
Tails: write the absolute value of the difference between the two numbers above

Here is an example, with $p=\frac13$. Heads (sum) are in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$, Tails (difference) are in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.
$$
1\\
1\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{blue}{2}\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{red}{1}\quad \color{red}{1}\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{red}{0}\quad \color{blue}{2}\quad \color{red}{0}\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{red}{1}\quad \color{red}{2}\quad \color{red}{2}\quad \color{red}{1}\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{blue}{2}\quad \color{blue}{3}\quad \color{red}{0}\quad \color{red}{1}\quad \color{red}{0}\quad 1\\
1\quad \color{red}{1}\quad \color{blue}{5}\quad \color{red}{3}\quad \color{blue}{1}\quad \color{red}{1}\quad \color{red}{1}\quad 1\\
\cdots
$$
What is the expected average of all the numbers in the triangle, as a function of $p$?
That is,

What is $L_p=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\text{(expectation of the arithmetic mean of all numbers in the first $n$ rows)}$ as a function of $p$?


$p=1$ and $p=0$
When $p=1$, it's just the normal Pascal's triangle ("NPT"). Therefore $L_1=\infty$.
When $p=0$, each number in the coin-based Pascal's triangle ("CPT") is $1$ just if the corresponding number in the NPT is odd, otherwise $0$ (this is because the sum and difference of two numbers have the same parity). The proportion of odd numbers in the NPT approaches $0$ as the number of rows approaches infinity. Therefore $L_0=0$.

$0<p<1$
I used Excel to simulate $500$ row triangles with $p=0.12$, $p=0.07$ and $p=0.01$.
I also include $p=0$ for comparison.
$A(n)=\text{arithmetic mean of all numbers in the first $n$ rows}$.




Perhaps there is a critical value of $p$, above which $L_p=\infty$, and below which $L_p<\infty$.
Or perhaps $L_p=\infty$ for all $p>0$, but for very small positive values of $p$, the triangle takes a while to "get going" towards infinity.

Context
This question was inspired by a question about a variation of Pascal's triangle in which half the time we write $0$ instead of adding the two numbers above.

For ease, let $c_{n,m} = \mathbb{E}(C_{n,m})$ be the expectation value of the $n,m$th entry $C_{n,m}$. Is there any hope that a crude inequality like
$$\begin{split}c_{n,m} &= p(c_{n-1,m-1}+c_{n-1,m}) + (1-p)\mathbb{E}(|C_{n-1,m-1}-C_{n-1,m}|) \& = (c_{n-1,m-1}+c_{n-1,m})  - 2(1-p)\mathbb{E}[\min({C_{n-1,m-1}, C_{n-1,m}})] \& \geq  (c_{n-1,m-1}+c_{n-1,m})- 2(1-p)\min({c_{n-1,m-1}, c_{n-1,m}})\end{split}$$ might show that $L_p$ diverges for all $p>0$?

@user196574: For $p>1/2$, the inequality is enough to ensure divergence. However, for $p\le 1/2$, the lower bound provided on $c_{n,m}$ is less than $\max(c_{n-1,m-1},c_{n-1,m})$.
